# Symfony OptionResolver: how to check that of two options only one is set

Tags: symfony

I have to validate the configuration of the Amazon MWS `ListOrders` call.

This call [accepts both `CreatedAfter` and `LastUpdatedAfter`](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IT/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html), but only one of the two, not both at the same time.

So, how can I check this condition with `OptionResolver`?

I think I can do [something like this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html#options-without-default-values):

```
$resolver = new OptionsResolver();
$resolver->setDefined(['CreatedAfter', 'LastUpdatedAfter']);
$resolver->setAllowedTypes([...]);
```

But at this point how can I check the condition that only one is set?

I would like to do this during the `$resolver->resolve()` call.

Or should have I first resolve the options and then check that only one of them is set using the `is*()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... only one of the two, not both at the same time.

Implement `setNormalizer()` when you want to validate any option value before it's set:

```
$resolver->setDefined(['CreatedAfter', 'LastUpdatedAfter']);

$resolver->setNormalizer('CreatedAfter', function (Options $options, $value) {
    if (null === $value xor null === $options['LastUpdatedAfter']) {
        return value;
    }

    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Both options are null or both options are being provided');
});
```

Comment: Ok, perfect! Thank you!